# How to sum all values of checked checkboxes using alpinejs

Tags: checkbox, sum, alpine.js

Hi have a custom form where I want to sum the values of all checked checkboxes using alpinejs.

Something like this:

```
<div x-data="price : 0">
  <input @click="price = 200"  type="checkbox" name="event1" value="200">
  <input @click="price = 299" type="checkbox" name="event2" value="299">
  <p x-text="total"></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using @change event and asking wether the input is checked or not to sum or subtract from total.

```
<div x-data="{price : 0}">
  <input @change="price += ($event.target.checked) ? +$event.target.value : -$event.target.value"  type="checkbox" name="event1" value="200">
  <input @change="price += ($event.target.checked) ? +$event.target.value : -$event.target.value"  type="checkbox" name="event2" value="299">
  <p x-text="price"></p> 
</div>
```

EDIT:

Added a pen with this example:
https://codepen.io/victor-cortes/pen/LYbMVqb

Answer (score 0):

A little late to the post but I wanted to share an iteration of Victor Cortes answer.
I had a problem with decimal point arithmetic since JS float has accuracy issues, this was my solution:

```
<input @change="$event.target.checked ? moneyFormat(+$event.target.value) : moneyFormat(-$event.target.value)"  type="checkbox" name="" value="{{ $row['money'] }}" >
```

on stage have output element:
`<p id="my-val" class=""></p>`

call a function to clean up math:

```
<script>
const precisionRound =(number, precision)=>{
    var factor = Math.pow(10, precision)
    return Math.round(number * factor) / factor
}

let vv = 0
const moneyFormat =(num)=> {

  vv += num
  vv = precisionRound(vv, 2)
  
  // clean float to 2 decimals
  let val = (vv).toLocaleString(
    undefined, // leave undefined to use the visitor's browser 
    { minimumFractionDigits: 2 }
  );

  document.getElementById('my-val').innerText = '$' + val
}
</script>
```